# Vscode codespaces not highlighting my JavaScript/React/TypeScript files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, codespaces

I’m new to Codespaces, been trying to use it to write code from my iPad Pro.
It looks good and promising but I can’t get the highlighting to work, already have “JavaScript React” selected as a language on the bottom bar, changed the configurations and installed extensions... no luck.
I see a moon emoji in front of my JS files in my project.
Any idea on how to fix this?

Thank in advance!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FuHE.jpg)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your vs code bottom bar and file shown?

Comment: I’ve just added a screenshot there now, hope it helps!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the needed extensions? If so, check the logs in the output panel, it might be failing for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can install this extension to get syntax highlighting in visual studio codespaces:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=evgeniypeshkov.syntax-highlighter